# How to check file size in CAPL

Tags: capl

hello CAPL professors.

I ran into a problem while doing CAPL.
Opening the file and reading its contents is not a problem.

but, How to check file size in CAPL??

Would you tell me a code or function that can measure file size in CAPL?